# Syntax Error when trying to run a program?

Tags: python

New to python. I keep getting this syntax error when I'm using commands from a tutorial.

```
>>> ls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ls' is not defined
>>> python cupp.py -i
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python cupp.py -i
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> ls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ls' is not defined
>>> print("Books")
Books
```

[screenshot of syntax error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHh6b.png)
[screenshot of ls syntax error in juptyr notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBNg7.png)
The print command works but nothing else. I've googled this error for some explanation but to no avail. Any advice or tutorial links I should follow? Thank you.

Comment: Shell commands won't work in the python shell. Python code will.

Answer (score 0):

You are running a shell command (`ls`) which isn't a python command. To list a directory in python:
`Import os

os.listdir(path)
`

Comment: I suppose the tutorial is giving me shell commands rather than python commands. In what context can I use shell commands? I want to run the program cupp.py and the tutorial says to simply type "python cupp.py" which doesn't work.

Comment: Separate the python shell from the regular shell (Terminal).
commands like ls or python cups.py are ran from the terminal.
Python code is ran from a python shell or .py file using `python file.py` command in the terminal

Comment: Thank you, I am reading about the python shell. Do you have any information on how to separate the python shell from the regular shell? Or if you can direct me to a tutorial for how to do that, it would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Terminal is the default shell. All the commands are used in there.
Python shell will start when you type in `python` in the terminal and will usually show >>>  while the terminal will not. That is an easy way to know in which shell you are currently writing